# how can i real time update the text without affecting other event(pyqt)

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

in my program, i would like to continually set text into text browser, but it seem to have delay when i click another button. There is my code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.th0 = TestThread()
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.runthread)

  def runthread(self):
    self.th0.start()
    self.chilWid.Consumer()
    QtGui.qApp.processEvents()

  def setupUi(self, Widget):             
    self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.chilWid = ChildWid()
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.chilWid, 1, 0, 1, 1)

    self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)

manager = Manager()
manager2 = Manager()
q = manager.Queue()
q2 =manager2.Queue()
l = manager.Lock()
l2 =manager2.Lock()
```

this class is a thread that will control the producer

```
class TestThread(QThread):
 def __init__(self):
    QThread.__init__(self)
    self.t = ChildWid()
 def run(self):
    while (not self.stopped):
        ps0 = Process(target=Producer, args=(q, l, 'eth0', q2, l2))        
        #### Producer is another program that will generate 
             text continually and save into q
        ps0.start()
```

this class only contain a text browser and will be inserted by class MainWindow. it also collects the data from queue and display it on text browser

```
class ChildWid(QWidget):
 def __init__(self):
    QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.text = QTextEdit()
    self.lay = QHBoxLayout(self)
    self.lay.addWidget(self.text)

 def Consumer(self):
    global q, q2, q3,l,l2,l3
    while True:
        try:
            task = q.get(block=False)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            self.text.setText(str(task))
        except:
            pass
```

when i click `pushButton`, text browser will display the text generate by `Producer`  normally. But another button like `pushbutton` or whole user interface response are very slow. dose any suggestion for me? thanks

**********new updated

```
class TestThread(QThread,QObject):
testsinal = pyqtSignal(str)

def __init__(self):
     . . .
    self.t = ChildWid()

def TestSignal(self):
    self.testsinal.emit('some text message')
    self.testsinal.connect(self.handle)
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def handle(self,str):
    print str
    self.t.text.setText(str)

def run(self):
    print"Thread run normally"
    while (self.stopped):
        ps0 = Process(target=L2PS_v1a4.main, args=(q, l, 'eth0', q2, l2, q3))
        ps0.start()

        self.TestSignal()
```

Comment: Try `self.text.update()` after `self.text.setText(str(task))`

Comment: it doesn't work, the problem still existing :(

Comment: I made a mistake, you need to call `self.text.repaint()` for an immediate repaint

Comment: thanks, after using  'repaint()' the text can be continually displayed, but the whole user interface response is still slow. i cant click another button

Comment: it seems that the button have their response, but the GUI response is slow. that mean when i click the button, the effect of button is shown but   the GUI will show the button with clicked status after a moment

Comment: I'm not a specialist in Python and I can not fully understand your code. But I think the problem is that you wait for working thread finish is the the main (GUI) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `Consumer` method with the blocking `while` loop looks really nasty. It's trying to act like some kind of fake event-loop, but there's no way that it can operate as efficiently as the real thing. Get rid of it.

The correct way to do this is to define a custom signal on the `TestThread` class, and then use it to emit the text messages from within the `run()` method. Cross-thread signals are thread-safe, and are posted to the receiving thread's event-queue. This means they are processed asynchronously, and so won't block the GUI:

```
class TestThread(QThread):
    testSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    ...

    def run(self):
        while (not self.stopped):
            ps0 = Process(target=Producer, args=(q, l, 'eth0', q2, l2))        
            ps0.start()
            self.testSignal.emit('some text message')


class ChildWid(QWidget):
    ...

    QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def handleTestSignal(self, message):
        print(message)
        self.text.setText(message)


class Ui_MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.th0.testSignal.connect(self.chilWid.handleTestSignal)
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but how to emit the text message from run()? the pyqt document say emit function is for emitting a signal?

Comment: @RforMaser. Well, yes - exactly. See my updated answer. You just need to connect a slot to the `messageSent` signal.

Comment: but my slot cannot execute `self.t.text.setText(str)`. the slot method can execute `print str`.  see my updated code

Comment: @RforMaser. Your updated code is wrong. The worker thread and the GUI must be kept *completely* separate. The thread just does non-GUI work in the background and emits a signal when it has new results. The GUI receives these signals asynchronously, and updates its widgets accordingly. All GUI operations **must** happen in the main thread. See my updated answer for how the code should be structured.